# gcc: undefined reference to `fy_library_version'

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I'm trying to check if my installation of libfyaml was successful since I have to use the library in a project. I built it from source and the installation went fine, but when I compile the test program using `gcc test.c -o test`, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPsUk6E.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `fy_library_version'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the path and indeed `libfyaml.h` is located in `/usr/local/include`. The path is also fine, and GCC lists it as path for headers. I have tried using the `-I`, `-l` and `-L` options, too. However, it still gives the same error.

How do I fix this issue? I'm on Ubuntu 20 (WSL).

Test program for reference:

```c
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <libfyaml.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", fy_library_version());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Link to library: [Github](https://github.com/pantoniou/libfyaml)

Comment: You need `-l`. How exactly did you try to use it?

Comment: Unless the library is a header-only library (where all functionality is in the header files) there's an actual library that you need to link with. How did you install the library into your system? Did you build it yourself from source? Use a package manager? If you built it from source, did it build an actual library file (a file named something like `libfyaml.a` or similar)? If you installed with a package manager just try adding `-lfyaml` at the end of the command line when you build.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I used it with -llibfyaml. I see what I did wrong, sorry, this is the first time I'm using a non-default library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I built it from source, and its just `libfyaml.h` file in the include folder.

Comment: Is there a `lib` directory? What files does it contain?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I did not look into that directory before. Ignore my earlier comment. Yes, there are .a, .la, .so, .so.0 and a .so.0.0.0 files for libfyaml

Comment: *libfyaml.h is located in /usr/local/include.* Side note about interpreting error messages: The error message you get is not about a missing header. If `libfyaml.` wasn't in any folder the compiler is looking into, you would get a different message indicating that this file was not found. Instead your linker is telling you that some symbol that you are using, is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has two major components: the compiler and the linker. Including the headers is the part you are doing right, and you are basically letting the compiler know that `fy_library_version` is invoked with the correct arguments and return type.

However, the compiler does not know what happens after calling such function, and the duty of checking that any code for that function exists is deferred to a later stage: the linker.

The linker is indeed what is throwing the error you see

> ld returned 1 exit status

This is because the linker does not know which libraries you are using and hence can't know where to find the code for you functions. To fix that you should tell gcc which libraries you are using:

```
gcc test.c -lfyaml -o test
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I tried with -llibfyaml which ofcourse didn't work. How do you deduce the library name `fyaml` from `libfyaml`?

Comment: It's a convention, usually if the lib is called libsomething you link with -lsomething.

Answer (score 1):

When you include libraries, you need to pass the `-l` argument to the compiler

Don't quote me on this, but judging by the name, the library name would be "fyaml", so the command goes as follows
`gcc test.c -o test.o -lfyaml`